# Trim en LINQ con WPF

Tags: c#, linq

hay alguna manera de realizar un trim a una columna de un query en c# ?

he intentado lo siguiente

```
        var comboGuardado = cbxIdTipoEventoContrato.SelectedValue;
        if(Convert.ToInt32(comboGuardado) == 10) 
        {

            Brick.OnBreakEntities bbdd = new Brick.OnBreakEntities();
            var llenarCoffee = (from mod in bbdd.ModalidadServicio
                                where mod.IdTipoEvento.Equals(10) select new{ idt = mod.IdModalidad, nomb = mod.Nombre.Trim()}).ToList();



            cbxIdModalidadContrato.ItemsSource = llenarCoffee;
            cbxIdModalidadContrato.SelectedValuePath = "idt";
            cbxIdModalidadContrato.DisplayMemberPath = "nomb"; 

        }
```

He intentado también poner el trim en

```
cbxIdModalidadContrato.DisplayMemberPath = "nomb".Trim();
```

pero aún así, al compilar, de cualquiera de las dos formas me da así

tengo entendido que mi select es una lista, pero como acceder a solo determinado dato de ella?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: si inspeccionas poniendo un breakpoint despues de la ejecucion del linq, la variable `llenarCoffee` puedes ver que la propiedad `nomb` tiene espacios en el texto?

Comment: he intentado poniendo un breakpoint después de la consulta Linq, pero no sé como ver que contiene la propiedad seleccionada

Answer (score 0):

```
cbxIdModalidadContrato.DisplayMemberPath = "nomb".Trim();
```

Esta instruccion lo que hace es hacerle trim al string nomb no a la propiedad en si lo que necesitas hacer es un nuevo campo en tu clase `ModalidadServicio`

```
public string NombTrim {
    get{ return nomb.Trim(); }

}
```

y

```
cbxIdModalidadContrato.DisplayMemberPath = "NombTrim";
```

Comment: he intentado tu solución, pero no me funciona debido a que todo mi código mostrado aquí está dentro de un evento DropDownClosed de un combobox, y cuando intento crear la función fuera del evento, no me encuentra la propiedad "nomb". Por otra parte si lo creo dentro del evento, el error incrementa y todos los caracteres siguientes quedan marcados con error de sintaxis

Comment: He intentado también hacer un llamado global de la consulta, para acceder a la propiedad nomb desde cualquier parte, pero no sé donde poner ese llamado global para que todos los demás eventos los ocupen